# Unable to uninstall vscode from my computer

Tags: visual-studio-code

the app does not show up in the control panel and I've gone through %appdata% deleted any file that says anything about vscode and I have tried launching the installer again hoping that it would give me a option to uninstall it but instead it just downloads it again without realizing I already have it downloaded. If anyone knows what to do or just a idea on what to do that would be great.

Comment: How do you know that it is not uninstalled yet?

Comment: I can still launch it.

Comment: Hi @hashdankhog welcome to stackoverflow, you're description seems to be a bit vague. For example try explaining if you checked it after uninstalling or happend to reinstall it just after uninstalling(this is what I get when I read your description).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin rights to install the visual studio code.Try for run as administrator.

Also facing any issues as below.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45889

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92461

Comment: Yes I do have admin rights. I don't get any errors when trying to delete stuff but I might try restarting which is ironic in a way because the one thing I didn't try is the simplest.